# Using $location.absUrl in controller breaks tests, how would I mock it?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I've read a couple of threads on this but can't figure out a solution to my problem. In my controller I have a function:

```
this.dName = function() {
    var url = $location.absUrl();
    var matches = url.match(/\/dName\/(.*)$/);
    return matches[1];
};
```

This causes my tests to fail as there is no absolute url to grab. How would I go about mocking `$location.absUrl` so that my tests can pass?

Comment: You can mock `absUrl` method. Or `$location` service all together.

Comment: Great. I'm still learning how to do these things could you perhaps provide a little more information on how?

Comment: What testing framework do you use?

Comment: @dfsq I'm using Karma

Comment: @sWright karma is a test runner, most often people use it with the jasmine framework, but there are other frameworks available, you can check which one your are using in your karma config file

Comment: @Tristan using Mocha

Answer (score 1):

For example you could spy on the `$location` service, in jasmine that would be:

```
describe('MyController', function(){

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));      

  var MyController, scope, $location;

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
    var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

    $location = $injector.get('$location');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    MyController = $controller('MyController', {
      $scope: scope,
    });
  }));

  it('Check dName', function () {

    spyOn($location, 'absUrl').and.returnValue(["match0", "match1"]);

    var match = scope.dName();

    expect(match).toEqual("match1");
    expect($location.absUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, would you happen to know how to write this for Karma?

Comment: karma is a test-runner, not a framework. The above code is written in Jasmine which is a framework. Which framework are you using - mocha/jasmine or anything else?